# Repeatable builds

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Recently we had this case:

[image]

We have multiple projects in our solution that depend on each other. With project dependencies we make sure the project is build in the right order.

In the case above a developer forgot to add a project dependency. Therefore 2 things could happen:
1. The build would fail because msbuild builds and outputs the projects in an order that does not work
2. The build would succeed because msbuild builds and outputs the projects in the right order (by accident)

As you can see above, the first nightly build succeeded, the second nightly did not, and the third succeeded again. This can be confusing. I would like to make the builds more repeatable, so that the consecutive builds either all fail or all succeed.

Is there an approach i can take to make this better?

I read about deterministic builds but i am unsure whether that would help my case:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/compilers/Deterministic%20Inputs.md

Additional info;
- The code is checkout clean before each build
- We use a plugin-based model so projects are not stitched together with project references, but plugin projects are build separately without dependencies. Then we reference the output dll from our application projects. Therefore the plugin should be built before the application project. We manually add project dependencies to make sure this happens.

Comment: Did you check the build log for the failed builds?

Comment: @OguzOzgul i did and it was due to the build order like i mention in my question. Its not aboud the error - its about getting builds that build the same way given the same files to build.

Comment: Ok, parallel builds and sometimes luck is on your side. I see now.